# prove that $d(x,A)=d(x,a)$, for some $a\in A$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

$d(x,A)=\inf\{d(x,a):a\in A\}$

> Let, $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$. Let $A$ be a nonempty compact set. Then prove that $d(x,A)=d(x,a)$, for some $a\in A$.

Let, $d(x,A)=r$. Note that $d$ is a continuous function. Let, $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence in $A$ such that $d(x,a_n)\to r$ as $n\to\infty$.

Let, $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of closed sets of $A$ such that, $a_n\in C_n\in \mathcal{C}$ with $\mathcal{C}$ has *finite intersection property*.

Since, $A$ is compact, $\bigcap C_n$ is nonempty and is a subset of $A$. Then, because of continuity of $d$, there exist a point $a\in \bigcap C_n$, such that $r=d(x,a)$ which proves the result.

Is my solution OK? Any help appreciated.

Comment: How you define $d(x,A)$? How do you know that there is a sequence $d(x,a_n)\to r$? It might be complete, but I do not know if anything is missing because I do not know what you know/are supposed to know. Can you use that compact implies closed? That $d(x,\cdot)$ is continuous?

Comment: How can you simply say the intersection of the closed sets is nonempty? Have you ensure the finite intersection property?

Comment: If $d$ is a metric on $X$ then $d$ is a function from $X \times X$ to $\mathbb R$. But $A \subset X$ and not $A \in X$. So what is $d(x,A)$? $d$ is not defined on subsets of $X$ but rather elements of $X$.

Comment: @M.Winter I am very sorry for your inconvenience. I had to go a place at that time (that is why I could not gave a reply immediately.) I added info abt $d(x,A)$, and $d(x,A)$ is continuous for a given $A\subset X$.

Comment: @AritroPathak I forgot to write that $\mathcal{C}$ has *finite intersection property*. I added that part now.

Comment: @OriaGruber $d(x,A)$ is defined for a fixed $A\subset X$

Comment: And what if $\mathcal C=\{A\}$? Sorry but your solution is not okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U_n:=\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)>d(x,A)+\frac1{n}\}$.

Then $U_n$ is open with $U_1\subseteq U_2\subseteq\cdots$.

Now assume that no $a\in A$ exists with $d(x,A)=d(x,a)$.

Then $A\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n$ and since $A$ is compact we get $A\subseteq U_m$ for some $m$.

Then $d(x,y)>d(x,A)+\frac1{m}$ for all $y\in A$ so that $d(x,A)\geq d(x,A)+\frac1{m}$.

A contradiction is found.

Comment: Thanks a lot for an another solution! Can you please check mine if I have done anything wrong.(It has been edit since you last saw, I added some important info)

Comment: You can do it with finite intersection but must use suitable sets $C_n$. For instance the sets $A\cap U_n^{\complement}$ here.

Comment: Yeah! I clearly understand now where I was doing wrong. If I use the set you mention here, I do not need to thing all the other stuff I did in my solution. I can not choose arbitrary $C_n$, choosing arbitrary $C_n$ is where I was doing wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I feel good that someone arbitrarily comes here and put afford to check all of what is wrong, what is good, gives a counterexample... feel proud to be a member of such community. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are very welcome

Answer (score 2):

No, why would it be guaranteed that $\bigcap C_n$ be non-empty? Take for example $C_n = \{a_n\}$ and assume that $a_0\ne a_1$ (which we can arrange for if $|A|\ge 2$).

Instead you use the fact that since $A$ is compact that $a_n$ has a convergent subsequence (since $A$ is compact).

Another solution would be that since $d(x,a)$ is continuous with respect to $a$ so it has a minima on $A$ which is $d(x,A)$.

Comment: I forgot to write that $\mathcal{C}$ has *finite intersection property*. I added that part now. Is my argument ok then?

Comment: I can not use the fact you used in the second paragraph (because it is in the next chapter in the book I am following) and I know the way you wrote in the third paragraph. But I want to prove this problem only using the definition of compactness (Although the solution become bigger)

Comment: I'm not sure. You still need to motivate why you think that such a family exists - just saying that $\mathcal C$ has the FIP isn't enough.

Answer (score 2):

The extreme value theorem says that the continuous function $d(t,x)$ for $t \in A$ attains its minimum somewhere on the compact set $A$, and hence by definition of $d(x,A)$, that is where the value of $d(x,A)$ is attained.

Comment: I know this solution. But I want to prove this problem only using the definition of compactness (Although the solution become bigger). Sorry that I forgot to mention some important elements at first (because I was in a hurry at that moment)

Comment: I love one line answers! Thanks for writing it for us!